# Change Renderer color

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity engine

how to put color on the cube ?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class cor_cube : MonoBehaviour {

public Color colorStart = Color.red;
public Color colorEnd = Color.green;
public float duration = 1.0F;
public Renderer rend;
void Start() {
    rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
}
void Update() {
    float lerp = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, duration) / duration;
    rend.material.color = Color.Lerp(colorStart, colorEnd, lerp);
    }
} (I don't want like that)
```

I want a fixed color.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want a fixed color.

It looks like you don't want to `lerp` from one color to another. You just want to set the color.

Below are the ways to change color:

**Method 1**: Predefined Colors

```
void Start() {
    rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    rend.material.color = Color.blue;
}
```

There many other predefined Colors such as `Color.blue`,`Color.white`,`Color.black`,`Color.green` and `Color.gray`.

**Method 2**: Custom Color with RGB or RGBA values

You can also create a custom color that is NOT defined in the `Color` structure. 
The format is in RGBA(Red,Green,Blue,Alpha). The values are float numbers from **0.0** to **1.0**.

Full Red Color
`rend.material.color = new Color(1,0,0,1);`

Full Blue Color

```
rend.material.color = new Color(0,1,0,1);
```

Full Green Color

```
rend.material.color = new Color(0,0,1,1);
```

Half Way Visible Blue Color

```
rend.material.color = new Color(0,1,0,0.5f);
```

Hidden Blue Color

```
rend.material.color = new Color(0,1,0,0);
```

**Method 3**: HSV Color

```
rend.material.color = Color.HSVToRGB(0,0,0);
```

I can't go on and on but this should get you started. Make sure to create a material in Editor and assign it to the cube so that the default one wont be used. You only need to create one and use it for all your cubes. When you change the color, a new material will be created for you. If you don't want that, use `rend.sharedMaterial.color` instead of `rend.material.color`.

In Unity 5, things changed. To get the alpha to change, you have to select the material and change the **Rendering Mode** from Opaque(default) to Fade or Transparent. So old tutorials may not work because of this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a material with the shader Unlit/diffuse on it. Set the texture to a plain white texture adn set the color of the material.

Comment: I have 31 cubes, I have to create 31 material ?

Comment: No, at runtime each Cube will get its own instance of the material